# Label Background Color Change According to text Coming from Server

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, for-loop, uilabel

I want to change label background color according to text coming from server if Send(text) is coming. The background color will be red and other will be green.

My for loop is working properly. but the color is showing me green on all labels.

And the (types) is a globally decleared  variable.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRID") as! HomeCell



    for all in (arrayForType)!
    {
        print(all)
        let types = (all as AnyObject).object(forKey: "type") as! String
        print(types)

       if types == "Send"
        {
            cell.lblForSend.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        else
        {
            cell.lblForSend.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }

    }
    return cell
    }
```

Comment: What was logged when you call `print(types)`?

Comment: it is printing step by step and it is going both if,  else  condition according to text.

Comment: In this case, all labels should have red color. Right?

Comment: yes correct. so have you any suggestion.

Comment: Can you post the output of `print(all)`? or the whole `arrayForType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the problem is because on the loop, after change background color to red, you get another text which isn't `Send` and it makes your labels come back to green color

You can try my below code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRID") as! HomeCell

  let types = (arrayForType[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "type") as! String

  if types == "Send"
  {
    cell.lblForSend.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
  } else {
    cell.lblForSend.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
  }

  return cell
}
```

Comment: This is not working all text's background color are showing same

Comment: I asked that all labels should have red color and you say yes? Read the comments on question

Comment: ohh... I am so sorry actually I want to change it according to text.if the send is showing on label the color will be red and if received is showing on label then the color will be green.